# Python MySQLdb doesn't return all the data from the database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using the Python package `MySQLdb` to fetch data from a MySQL database.  However, I notice that I can't fetch the entirety of the data.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password)

cur = db.cursor()

query = "SELECT count(*) FROM table"
cur.execute(query)
```

This returns a number less than what I get if I execute the exact same query in MySQL Workbench.  I've noticed that the data it doesn't return is the data that was inserted into the database most recently.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not committing the inserted rows on the other connection.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: send a `COMMIT`

Comment: Sorry but what's the code and where should I put it?

Comment: When you insert the rows using workbench, your connection can see the rows it just inserted. Other connections can't, as long as the transaction is not committed. Send a `COMMIT` from Workbench after you inserted the rows and both `COUNT(*)` will match.

Comment: I'm not inserting any rows from Workbench.  I don't have edit permissions for the database.  I can only view it.

Comment: If I order a table by date in the Python script, the most recent date is a few months back, whereas on Workbench it's much more recent than that.

Comment: Then you are probably not on the same database :-)

Comment: Hold on you're absolutely right!  I checked the credentials again and it turns out I was using the default port number which wasn't the right one.